# If a $f\in\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ is integral over $\mathbb{C}[t]$, convergent for $|t| < r$, then does it extend to a continuous function on $|t|\le r$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f = \sum_n c_nt^n \in\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ be a power series, and suppose it is integral over the subring $\mathbb{C}[t]$ (ie,it satisfies a monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}[t]$). Suppose $f$ has a positive radius of convergence $r$. Must $f$ extend to a continuous function on the closed disk $\{t\in\mathbb{C} : |t|\le r\}$?

Comment: Where do the tags (algebraic-geometry) and (commtuative-algebra) come from, here? Do you have a specific situation where you want this result to hold?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I'm looking at remark 2 of https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/83588/1/0844-21.pdf

Comment: Consider the power series $f(z) = \sum_{n\geqslant 0} f_n z^n$, say it has positive radius of convergence $r$, and suppose you can write $f^n = \sum_{j<n} p_j f^j$
for some polynomials $p_j$. Then writing $1 = \sum_{j<n} p_j / f^{n-j}$ shows that $f$ cannot be unbounded along any sequence approaching a boundary point, else you would obtain that $1=0$. Does this help?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff To be clear, am I correct in understanding what you've written as a proof (in the positive?)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Is it true that for any boundary point $z$, and any sequence $z_n$ with limit $z$ where $z_n$ is in the interior of the convergence disk, that if $f(z_n)$ is bounded, then it converges, and moreover $\lim_n f(z_n)$ is independent of the choice of the sequence $z_n$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Said another way, if $z_n\rightarrow z$ as above, then is it true that if $f(z_n)$ converges, then its limit equals $\sum_n c_nz^n$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I've also slightly changed the question (I want the boundary function to be continuous)

Comment: Well, I haven't claimed I've proved anything, just that it might help. :)